# input type file setting default file type

Tags: html, file-upload, input

How would you configure the file upload window to default *.csv files. I'm not particularly concerned about it preventing users from entering *.* or putting it back to all files, just as a convenience to users to autocratically filter out irrelevant files.

Answer (score 0):

File input elements do have an `accept` attribute which according to the specification, should determine the MIME type of files to be allowed. However, most browsers do not support this.

Therefore the only method available to you is to check the file extension of the value on submission of the form against the filetypes you would like to allow.

Comment: I'm not interested in this for any server side or validation concerns, I want to set it to *.csv for a better user experience. or is it just not interoperable in anyway whatsoever?

Comment: I didn't mean server side. You can check the file extension in javascript when the form is submitted, and block the process if the file is not in the correct format. I'm just putting a fiddle together for you but it's being stupidly slow.

Comment: Once again, I'm not doing this for any validation purposes, I don't care what users upload, I want to provide users the best experience which is by default having them see the most likely files they **should** upload. It's not a great experience trying to pick a csv out of a folder with 20+ other files if you're not a power user that has experience to know you can do *.csv enter, then see only csvs.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I misunderstood your request. No it's not possible to restrict what file types are shown in the file dialog in a web browser.

Comment: You can limit what file types users can upload if you use Flash.